# Type 'Model' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'/Encodable

Tags: ios, encoding, swiftui, decodable

I can't figure out how I can fix this error.

If I remove @Published, it compiles everything correct but then I can't see the data in a cell in real time. Reading I saw that I need the var with `@Published`

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TimeModel: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var nome : String
    @Published var time : String
    
    func aggiornaUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    init(nome: String, time: String) {
        self.nome = nome
        self.time = time
    }
    
}
```

Update: ok thanks I check now but the error remain

```
        HStack {
            Text("\(timeString(from: Int(TimeInterval(remainingSeconds))))")
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if isCounting && remainingSeconds > 0 {
                        remainingSeconds -= 1
                    }
                }
```

error:

> Instance method 'onReceive(_:perform:)' requires that 'TimeModel'
> conform to 'Publisher'

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve with this code because you're mixing many concepts together. If I see `Codable` I think that you need to serialize/deserialize this object from some kind of persistence layer but then I see `SwiftUI` related protocols which are a presentation layer concern and you're also using `DispatchQueue.main` internally. Are you dynamically changing `nome` and `time` from outside this class? When do you call `aggiornaUI`?

Comment: @FabioFelici at the moment updateUI is not used yet, I need it later when I will implement the possibility to modify the data from my app. 
this code I use it as a model, where. in my DataManager I am going to save my data in an array. then I recall the data I need from the various views in which I need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `@Published` property with type, let's say, `String`, are of type `Published<String>`. And apparently, that type is not `Codable`.

You can solve this by writing custom encode and decode functions. That's not difficult; it's only some extra lines of code. Please see the [documentation on `Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for some examples.

Here is an example for your case:

```swift
class TimeModel: Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var nome : String
    @Published var time : String
    
    func aggiornaUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    init(nome: String, time: String) {
        self.nome = nome
        self.time = time
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case nome
        case time
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(nome, forKey: .nome)
        try container.encode(time, forKey: .time)
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        nome = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .nome)
        time = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .time)
    }
}
```

This *should* work, but I can't really test it because I don't know the rest of your code.

Comment: ok thanks I check now but the error remain
I update the post with error

Comment: @user12147631 It looks like you have another error which is unrelated to the question. Please create another post explaining your problem.